# Xamarin Entry focus control with barcode reading

Tags: xamarin.forms

I lost my mind trying to make the focus change automatically between 3 entry field and an "OK" button!

I use a small android device that integrates a barcode reader. I set up the barcode reader to add a "enter key" when barcode is read. That call the OnEnterPressedCommand binded to my viewmodel, then I do some validation and send a message with messaging center to the view code-behind for the focus change.

When I use manually use the "enter" key on the virtual keyboard all work like expected. But when I scan the barcode (with the automatic enter) some focus on fields work, but some never got focus!

Does the virtual enter key work do not do the same thing that hitting adding a enter automatically??

Comment: is OnEnterPressedCommand getting fired every time?

Comment: yes, and the entry.focus() too. I suspected that maybe the enter key (in the field) add some delay... But I don't understand. Somethime I got an exception like "the view cannot set the focus...." (don't remember the exact message).

Comment: Please try to create an MVCE. See: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Maybe the automatic "enter" is called from another thread. Try this:
`Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => entry.focus());`

Comment: Thanks that seem to work! What a strange thing, enter from virtual keys and enter integrated with the string run on separate thread.... I will do more tests, but can you do a "real" answer so I can give you some credit for? Thanks.